# How can I set max line length in vscode for python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

For JavaScript formatter works fine but not for Python. I have installed autopep8 but it seems that I can't set max line length. I tried this:

```
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
    "--max-line-length",
    "79",
    "--experimental"
  ]
```

and my settings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
  "git.autofetch": true,
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
  },
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "vscode-w3cvalidation.validator-token": "Fri, 07 Aug 2020 07:35:05 GMT",
  "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
  "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
    "--max-line-length",
    "79",
    "--experimental"
  ],
  "python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
  "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": []
}
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Dunno about autopep8, but the recommended link length in [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is [79 characters](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) — so you may not be able to change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [autopep8-usage](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/#usage), the default value of max-line-length is 79, so you can change to other value and have a try.

About the effect of autopep8 in vscode, I made a test with the same settings as yours, like the following screenshot shows:

[image]

every `print` sentence line-length is over 79, the first and the second `print()` parameters are expressions, and the setting works for the first one, not for the second. This is because setting applicable rules are provided by python extension and it has own caculation mechanism.

When it comes to print strings, the setting doesn't work, so if you mean this in your question, you can add the following code in user settings.json.

```
"editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 79
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use  `"editor.wordWrap":"bounded",` incase you want to auto wrap width based on the window size.

Answer (score 3):

Specifically for autopep8:

```json
    "autopep8.args": [
        "--max-line-length", "119"
    ],
```

This is according to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-autopep8

Comment: this fixed the wrapping in my function, for example, render_arrays(rows1, MaxColumnWidth=10, RenderHeader=True, headers='name'). The last part was wrapped without your setting. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
    "--line-length",
    "119"
]
```

works for me